# python 3.6 vs 2.7 OS interpreter path

Tags: python, version, osx-yosemite

Probably a silly question, I am coming from another language (perl/C) and I had to install python for a new project (v 3.6) 
As I had this problem before in Perl to check which interpreter is doing what (not anymore with perlbrew),I checked with import sys and print (sys.version) and the system's one (2.7) is running. now I realized I did not brewed the python version I simply used the dmg from python.org and it seems that uninstalling is painful.
so long story short how do I find the interpreter path for the installed python?
tried with which--python and there is just the Library/Framework/../2.7
So have I done something wrong somewhere?

update

on macOS x yosemite v 10.10.5,

```
which -a python 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
which -a python 3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/3.6/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

shebang tried 
    #!/usr/bin/ env python (python3 and python 3.6)
    #!usr/local/bin/python (python3)

then I run the following using cd folder than python3 script name

```
#!/usr/bin env python3 (or any other shebang)
import sys, platform
print (sys.version)
print platform.python_version()
```

output is always

2.711 (v.2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775. Dec 5 2015. 12:54:16)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
2.7.11

Tried both in emacs / atom (my editors) and bash

Comment: You want to remove the existing installed `python`?

Comment: @Inian I simply want the script to be runned with the new installed version, I do not want to mess up with the system one but for portability we have to write it in 3.6, so I want either to remove the not brewed 3.6 and brew it or having a way for figuring out what went wrong in the installation of the newer version

Comment: Are you sure `Python v3.6` is installed?

Comment: Yes, there is the folder in the Application with IDLE, docs, Launcher and everything.

Comment: Is this for Mac OSX? If so, you should mention that in your question, preferably with the relevant tag.

Comment: Create an alias from `/usr/bin` to the python executable, maybe called `python3`.  You can then use the `#!` line to point to it.

Comment: FWIW, on Mac (& most Linux / Unix) systems, `python` refers to Python 2, and you need to specify `python3` or the specific version (eg `python3.6`) to use Python 3. That's because various system tools expect to use the system Python with the `python` command, and they expect that command to be Python 2.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes sorry I forgot to mention it, Ill'edit my question, yes macOS yosemite.  so simply modifiy the shebang with python 3.6? #!usr/bin/python3.6?

Comment: Hopefully, `python3` is linked to `python3.6`, so you can modify the shebang to use `python3`. It's generally not a good idea to specify exact versions in the shebang because then it won't work when you upgrade to 3.7. I can't offer more specific advice because I'm not on Mac: I (mostly) use a Debian derivative of Linux.

Comment: @PM2Ring okay for one second I really hoped it worked but sys.version is still saying 2.7. Damn, is present in lib/framework no idea why is not invoking it correctly

Comment: @D.A.: See if my answer helps

Comment: What does `which -a python3` show?

Comment: @jonrsharpe urs/local/bin/python3 and the v3.6 library/framework directory

Comment: Then it seems to be installed correctly. Just use `python3` instead of `python` to start the interpreter and execute your scripts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe still not working and running the 2.7 version.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of the shell command and/or script that leads to this; [edit] the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, updated

Comment: 1. *"then I run the following"* - how exactly? 2. Please show the actual shebangs in a runnable script, you seem to be doing them wrong. Try `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`.

Comment: cd in folder then python3 script name, added shebang